# Setting the map extent - spatial reference for wkid 27700

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinate-system

I want to set the extent of my basemap on application start but when I add the following code it doesn't seem to like it and renders a blank div?

```
map = new Map("map", {
    logo: false,
    extent: new esri.geometry.Extent("xmin="-377930, "ymin"=470972, "xmax"=849893, "ymax"=1269406,  new SpatialReference({ wkid: 27700 }))
});

initLayer();
baseMapServiceLayer = new my.BaseMap();
```

I wasn't sure if I should replace esri.geometry.Extent with Extent but that makes no difference - any help would be good!

Comment: According to the EPSG:27700 definition, the max extends are: [1393.0196, 13494.9764, 671196.3657, 1230275.0454]. Negative numbers could be the error: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/osgb-1936-british-national-grid/

Answer (score 1):

Stuff like:

```
"xmin="-377930, "ymin"=470972, "xmax"=849893, "ymax"=1269406
```

isn't valid as there aren't named (AKA keyword) arguments in JS (yet). Arguments to Extent are [positional](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/extent-amd.html#extent1) or you can use an [object](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/extent-amd.html#extent2).

Here's the how you should do it:

```
var bounds = new Extent({
  "xmin": -377930,
  "ymin": 470972,
  "xmax": 849893,
  "ymax": 1269406,
  "spatialReference": { "wkid": 27700 }
});
```

And a [full example showing a map in 27700 with a feature layer on it](http://jsbin.com/qasaco/edit?html,output).